# Convert format of date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date format like

```
'2003-11-27 00:00:00.000'
```

How can I convert it into `YYYYMMDD` like 20031127 WITH SQL SERVER ?

Comment: Dates don't have formats, they are binary types. What is the value you posted? The contents of a date/datetime field, the contents of a text field, a date literal?

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8),yourdatecolumn,112)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of how your date is declared.

```
DECLARE @date datetime = '2003-11-27T00:00:00.000' -- datetime
DECLARE @date2 char(23) = '2003-11-27 00:00:00.000' -- char(23)


SELECT
  convert(char(8), @date, 112) datetimeconvert, 
  convert(char(8), convert(datetime, @date2, 121), 112) charconvert
```

Result:

```
datetimeconvert charconvert
20031127        20031127
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert the date as per ISO standard you can write as:

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(),112) as [YYYYMMDD]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(8), cast('2003-11-27 00:00:00.000' as datetime), 112)
```

Answer (score 1):

The date types in SQL Server do not have any format, they are binary types. Formats apply only when you convert them to text or try to parse a text literal.

You don't specify *what* is the value you posted, or what you want to do with it. There are several possibilities:

- You want to truncate the time portion of a `datetime` field. Then just `cast(myField as date)`
- You want to create a text string containing the date portion of a `datetime` or `date` field: `FORMAT(myField,'yyyyMMdd')`  or `CONVERT(varchar(8),myField,112)`. FORMAT provides almost as much flexibility as .NET's String.Format but in this case CONVERT it's enough.
- You want to convert one text literal to another: `FORMAT(CONVERT(date,'2003-11-27 00:00:00.000',121),'yyyyMMdd')`. You convert the original string to a date then format it as you wish.